# Measures absolutely continuous wrt Dirac measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, absolute-continuity, product-measure

Suppose we have a probability space $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $x_0\in X$. Consider the measure $\mu\times \delta_{x_0}$, where $\delta_{x_0}$ is the Dirac measure at $x_0$. Then is it true that the probability measures which are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu\times \delta_{x_0}$ are of the form $\nu\times \delta_{x_0}$, where $\nu\ll \mu$?

Firstly, for any such $\nu$, it is immediate that $\nu\times \delta_{x_0}\ll \mu\times \delta_{x_0}$.

Suppose now that $\rho\ll \mu\times \delta_{x_0}$. Why would $\rho$ be of the form $\nu\times\delta_{x_0}$?

I feel that the only non-trivial measure absolutely cts wrt $\delta_{x_0}$ is $\delta_{x_0}$ so this would force $\rho$ to be of the required form. But I can not put it down in formally. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: What about $\mu \times (\frac{1}{2} \delta_{x_0})$?

Comment: Just saw this, sorry. I meant probability measures!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measure $\rho$ admits a density $f\colon X^2\to\mathbb R$ with respect to the measure $\mu\times \delta_0$. Letting 
$$
\nu(A):= \int_X f\left(x,x_0\right)d\mu(x),
$$
we can show that the measures $\nu\times\delta_{x_0}$ and $\rho$ coincide on finite disjoint unions of rectangles and since all the involved measures are finite, we derive that $\nu\times \delta_{x_0}=\rho$.